# Giving Navigation Bar Button functionality over segmented views

Tags: ios, calendar, uisegmentedcontrol, uinavigationitem, kal

I am having a problem with my iOS application that has Kal integrated into the application.

Heres an image of whats going on.

[image]

If you notice the classes I have implemented on the left part of the picture, you can sorta capture the way I went about this.

Anyways, I want to give the button "Today" functionality, but over all three segmented views, a perfect example is the native CALENDAR application the iPhone has preinstalled.

This tabbarcontroller is exactly the calendar app, or at least i want it to be.

I will provide any extra details if needed, i'll be sitting at my desk all weekend.

Thank you.

EDIT:

I currently have implemented the today button within the calendar_main class which is a parentviewcontroller of the other child view controllers (segmentedViews:list, day, month).

If needed, i can provide code.

Comment: I missed any question being asked.. whats your problem?

Comment: "I want to give the button, "Today", functionality, but over all three segmented views".